# What does DllRegisterServer generated by the VB6 compiler do?

Tags: com, vb6

When you compile a VB6 DLL the compiler adds an exported `DllRegisterServer()` function to the DLL.

**What exactly does this function do?**

I do understand that its purpose seems to be to add entries to the registry that allow all the COM magic to work... calling it

> "[Instructs an in-process server to create its registry entries for all
>   classes supported in this server module.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx)"

But I am interested in a specific, detailed specification for what it does. I haven't found any MSDN documentation on this. Does something like that exist? Has anyone disassembled that code and documented their findings?

---

Edit: One reason I'm interested in this is that I think there are cases where it doesn't work fully / successfully (even when regsvr32 reports success) and I'd like to understand these potential failure modes better.

Comment: This is not specifically documented, but it's quite standard COM: register InprocServer32 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390.aspx) with threading model (supported in VB) register TLB, that's about it. What's important is you must run DllUnregister server to rollback changes (before deleting the file...). If you really want details you can use registry diff tool such as https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html

Comment: I recommend you download the WiX Toolset (wixtoolset.org) and run your DLL through the `Heat` ("Harvest registry changes")  tool. It will generate an XML file with all the registry changes that correspond to your DLL.  If you pass the `-svb6` flag (you should), it will suppress a bunch of VB Runtime general keys that are not specific to your DLL or particularly interesting (you should not include those in an installer). Even if you don't use WiX to creat an installer, `Heat` is very instructive and helpful for tracking changes version-to-version.

Comment: There is nothing special about this function, it just writes some registry entries. If something does not work for you, you tell us what is that then.. the most frequent case is some third party ocx (control) missing.

Comment: @nikolay I sort of disagree... It is presumably crucial for allowing millions of lines of production code to run worldwide! And yet so far no one has provided any answers to precisely what it does. The function itself may be a boring one but the context seems quite unique and important.

Comment: I believe you may be lookibg in a wrong place.. it just writes com entries, as you specify them in class properties (those are documented in details) to the registry. Nothing else. There is no magic, all these com registry entries are also throughly documented in msdn.

Comment: What COM server needs is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678477(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is still specific to the special COM Server you have. A COM DLL may register 1 to n classes.And here is a little [summary](http://www.ewall.org/tech/msi/com-registration) about this.

Answer (score 0):

The function is used to register the DLL with the windows registry.  For example, if you call regsvr32.exe with the DLL name, the DLL will be loaded and then the regsvr32.exe utility will call the DllRegisterServer() function. What the function ought to do from a COM perspective is to make the PROGID, CLSID, and TypeLib entries in the Windows registry so that COM clients can create and use the COM object through CoCreateInstance().